# How to deal with missing variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an app in Angular, so any Angular specific answers are acceptable, however my question is to JavaScript at large.

My app used several JSON files to store information. Those JSON files are loaded in the `head` with `script` tags, and the objects inside them are assigned to variables in a service. There are 3 main JSON objects that I am working with, and some of them have dependencies on the others.

For example, one of them has a `Description` attribute which contains text combined with an expression, such as: `The value is {{10+(2*var)}}`.

However, one of the other objects has children, some of which may or may not be included at the time the `Description` is compiled. One child has a value that will be stored as `var2` and the other child doesn't.

If I change my expression to: `The value is {{(10+(2*var))*var2}}`, then the value will be valid only if the first child is used and defines `var2`. If the second child is used, `var2` is not defined, and as a result leave me with "NaN".

The best method I can think of, is to make another object that contains all possible values from sub children, and set them to default values, and then override them when a child with the value is present.

This has several downsides however. First off, I have to have all variables (there are a lot) present in yet another object, when most of them are not needed. I will also have to "reset" this object repeatedly.

Is there a more efficient, more standardized way of accomplishing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could default the variables directly in the template so you don't need to worry about existence or order of execution.

The text value would be:

```
The value is {{(10+(2*(var||1)))*(var2||1)}}
```

When `var2` is missing, it simply multiplies by 1.

You can also use ternary conditon in an Angular expression, such as

```
The value is {{(var2 ? 10+(2*var))*var2 : 10+(2*var))}}
```

Note: I would strongly recommend not naming a variable `var` as it is a keyword in javascript that could cause you trouble when trying to parse them with Angular (or in many other contexts).

Comment: Of course. var was just for the sake of brevity. Your first suggestion is likely what I'll go with, as there could be as many as 3-4 variables for some expressions. That'll save me a lot of time and files.

Comment: Great. That's a common way to have default bindings in angular, for instance `{{title || 'Hello world'}}`, things like that

Comment: Thanks, this is my first project with Angular, I appreciate the tips!

Comment: when var2 is zero, it also multiplies by 1.